# Como exibir duas tabelas no SQLDeveloper ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Não estou conseguindo filtrar duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo no SQL Developer ao mesmo tempo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando insiro duas tabelas ao mesmo no filtro o sqldeveloper não mostra nada!

Answer (score -1):

Conseguir visualizar apenas minhas tabelas seguindo esses passos:

1. Clicando com o botão direito do mouse encima do no da conexão
2. No menu que se abre, escolher a opção Aplicar Filtro...
3. Preencher segundo a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]